# Please help me with python loop/if statements

Tags: python, loops, if-statement, variable-assignment

***> Repeatedly loop, prompting the user to select an option, then running

> the appropriate commands and repeating until the user chooses to exit.
>   The options are: 0 to exit the program; 1 to calculate a flow rate for
>   a specific collection of values; 2 to calculate a Reynolds number, and
>   3 to plot expected flow rates. If the user selects any other option,
>   the program must keep asking them to select a valid value, until they
>   do so.***

while i<=3:

```
i=input (" Please enter a number between 0-3:")

if i==0:
    print " program will exit."
    break

elif i==1:
     print ( " To calculate flow rate please input these values:" )
     pressure = input (" Please enter pressure drop in pascals: " )
     radius = input  (" Please enter radius in m: " )
     viscosity = input  (" Please enter viscosity of liquid in Pa.s: ")
     Length= input  (" Please enter length in m: " )
     Flowrate = (pressure * pi *(radius**4))/ ( 8 * viscosity * Length)
     print " Therefore, flow rate is " , Flowrate
     print " Program will run again for user to calculate flow rate..."


elif i==2:
    print ( " To calculate reynolds number please input these values:" )
    q=input ("Please enter a value for flow rate in m^3/s")
    radius = input  (" Please enter radius in m: " )
    density=input   (" Please enter density in kg/m^3 : " )
    viscosity = input  (" Please enter viscosity of liquid in Pa.s: ")
    Rno=(2*q*radius*density)/(viscosity*pi*radius*radius)
elif i==3:
    print " not implemented yet."
else:
    print " Program will start again!"                          





    ***new edited post***
```

Answer (score 4):

One error I could spot is here:

```
Rno=(2*q*radius*density)/(viscosity*pi*radius*radius
```

Your code is missing a closing parenthesis.

Another (logical) error is that the `input()` call should be inside the loop, not outside it.

Comment: Recently, so many people are missing the `)` at the end of the line. Something weird is happening in this world.

Answer (score 1):

I typically have people lay out these sorts of programs like

```
while(True):
    i = input("<Prompt>")

    if(i==1):
        # Do something

    elif(i==2):
        # Do something else

    #... any additional elifs

    else: 
        break
```

Or like this

```
while(True):
    i = input("<Prompt>")

    if(i==1):
        # Do something

    elif(i==2):
        # Do something else

    #... any additional elifs

    elif(i==10):        # Assuming 10 here is the "exit" option
        break

    else: 
        print("Unknown selection, please try again")
```

The second version requires the user to explicitly select the "exit" option while the first version will simply exit when an unknown/undefined option is selected.

Comment: So im meant to have the i=.... in the loop but its saying variable is not defined.

Comment: @user2228719: Yes, otherwise you'll only call it once and not prompt the user again.

Comment: @user2228719: As long as your put the `i=...` in a place where it will always be called before any place you use it, you shouldn't get that error.  Make sure that line is the first line in your `while` loop.

Comment: Oh okay! I have put it in my loop, on the first line. But, you said its needs to be called before any place I'm using it. Im using it on the first line of the while statement, so do I need to introduce another variable or...get rid of the i somehow?

Comment: Can you edit your post to show your new code?

Comment: yup done. The indentations are not really shown cos I copied and pasted it from my program.

Comment: Your while loop's condition includes `i` -- thats why you're getting the error.  Change it to `while(True):` and add an `elif:` option for exiting similar to my code examples.

Answer (score 0):

You've said that your program should exit after user enters `0`, so I would change this:

```
if i==0 :
    print " program will exit."
    i=4
```

to this:

```
if i==0 :
    print " program will exit."
    break
```

And also, you don't need to assign `0` to `i` in the second `if`, because `i` is already equals `0` in this block, so you can safely delete this line of code.

Comment: Thanks everyone! :OOO I didn't expect such quick responses.